# How to remove specific samples using the filter function from a dataset?

Tags: python, r

**Dataset:**

`autompg = read.table( "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data", quote = "\"", comment.char = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

`head(autompg,20)`

`colnames(autompg) = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "wt", "acc", "year", "origin", "name")`

**complete the code segment below to remove samples with missing horsepower (hp) values represented as a “?” in the dataset.**

autompg = autompg %>% filter()

Can I combine with the ifelsefunction?
something like autompg = autompg %>% filter (nrow=ifelse(test_expression,x,?))

where I don't understand what the test_expression should be and what should be the vector value for x so that hp values are represented.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ifelse()` in this case because you're only filtering the dataset based on a condition.

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

autompg = autompg %>% filter(!is.na(hp) & hp != "?")
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried executing it and it says "Error in autompg %>% filter(!is.na(hp) & hp != "?") : 
  could not find function "%>%""

Comment: Try and load dplyr package before running the code 
This usually occurs when the package is not loaded or not available.
To resolve this, you need to load the dplyr package before using the %>% operator.